# jquery set div to toggle checkbox breaks clicking the checkbox itself

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I have this check box:

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
   <div class="InnerDiv">
      <input type="checkbox" name="tie" value="tie">Error in tie score<br>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have this jquery to toggle the checkbox:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.OuterDiv').click(function() {
      if ($(this).find('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) { 
         $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
      } else {
         $(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('checked',true);
      }
   });
});
```

This seems to work, to toggling the checkbox when clicking on the div. However when I click the checkbox itself, nothing happens and it does not toggle.

Comment: Why aren't you just using a `<label>` around the checkbox?

Comment: Your problem is that when you click on check box, check box itself toggles, then another toggle is done because of your code!

Comment: Side note: use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) rather than `.attr()`.

Comment: You should use `label`.  Its there for a reason.

Also,

When you click the checkbox, it checks the checkbox (the default functionality), but the event is propagated to `Outerdiv` and thus your function toggles it and you see no change

Comment: take a look at <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426258/how-do-i-check-a-checkbox-with-jquery-or-javascript">How do I check a checkbox with jQuery or JavaScript?</a> which says to use .prop() to jQuery 1.6+
and use .attr() to jQuery 1.5 and below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the propagation of the event bubbling up from your checkbox using [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Right. Cant this can be merged into the existing click by  `e.target` ?

Comment: @Jashwant I wouldn't know how that would work..  Can you make a fiddle with that technique?

Answer (score 2):

Without a `<label>` around the input (entire `DIV` is clickable) go for:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owewey/18/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.OuterDiv').click(function(e) {
     var $chkb = $(':checkbox', this)[0];
     if(e.target !== $chkb) $chkb.checked = !$chkb.checked; 
   });

});
```

**(No JS:)**
Else, if you just want the text next to the `checkbox` to be clickable:
<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/owewey/1/edit)**</kbd>

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
   <div class="InnerDiv">
     <label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="tie" value="tie">Error in tie score<br>
     </label>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not if there's a bunch of other stuff in `OuterDiv`

Comment: Sorry I disagree.  Are you sure your solution works w/o looking at op's CSS?

Comment: What I mean: http://jsbin.com/owewey/7/edit -- you're making an assumption that op *wants* a label.

Comment: @Madbreaks, You are making an assumption that op doesnt want a label :) +1 to compensate.

Comment: I posted the [similar](http://jsfiddle.net/q72dG/) solution in comment to  @wirey's answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use jQuery for this. Just use label tag as below:

```
<div class="OuterDiv">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="tie" value="tie">Error in tie score
    </label>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess, you dont see any answer / comment before posting your answer.